# Failed to open X11 display - How to execute SFML output on WSL - Load WSL GUI apps

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sfml, wsl-2

have any of you tried compile and executing SFML c++ project output on wsl?
I tried and got

```
Failed to open X11 display; make sure the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly
Aborted
```

Is it possible at all to execute GUI applications through wsl?

(I've installed ubuntu's for wsl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux distributions set up for WSL 1 will not function with Linux GUI applications, which are only supported with WSL 2.

Due to the official documentation from Microsoft regarding WSL, you might need to check these steps:

Select Start, type PowerShell, right-click Windows PowerShell, and then select Run as administrator.
after that type this command and then press enter:

```
wsl --update
```

You will need to restart WSL for the update to take effect. You can restart WSL by running the shutdown command in PowerShell.

```
wsl --shutdown
```

now, once again open powershell and type in this command:

```
wsl --list --verbose
```

You should see the number `2` for your installed distro under the heading `VERSION` in the response.

If everything went as planned until this point, see if your distro can open any windows by installing a GUI app like gedit and trying to open it:

```
sudo apt update
```

now install gedit:

```
sudo apt install gedit -y
```

After the installation has finished, launch gedit by typing `gedit` in your wsl terminal. A window from wsl inside of Windows should now open, and the issue should now be resolved.

find more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Answer (score 1):

If you had the same problem

first, you need to install [VcXsrv and X11](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) for executing GUI applications through wsl

then you have to add these 2 to your environment variables:

`export DISPLAY=:0`

`export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0`

Comment: but still make sure that you are on WSL version 2.